# bash script inside here document not behaving as expected

Tags: bash

Here is a minimal test case which fails

```
#!/bin/tcsh

#here is some code in tcsh I did not write which spawns many processes.
#let us pretend that it spawns 100 instances of stupid_test which the user kills
#manually after an indeterminate period

/bin/bash <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
if [[ `ps -e | grep stupid_test | wc -l` -gt 0 ]]
then
  echo 'test program is still running'
  echo `ps -e | grep stupid_test | wc -l`
  sleep 10
else
  break
fi
done
EOF

echo 'test program finished'
```

The stupid_test program is consists of

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do sleep 10; done
```

The intended behavior is to run until stupid_test is killed (in this case manually by the user), and then terminate within the next ten seconds.  The observed behavior is that the script does not terminate, and evaluates `ps -e | grep stupid_test | wc -l` == 1 even after the program has been killed (and it no longer shows up under ps)

If the bash script is run directly, rather than in a here document, the intended behavior is recovered.

I feel like I am doing something very stupidly wrong, I am not the most experienced shell hacker at all.  Why is it doing this?

Comment: If you want to call `bash`, then you need `/bin/bash << \EOF`, it is not a shebang then. The `\` because you don't want the subshells to be executed in the `tcsh` script. Plus the subshell after the `echo` is useless

Comment: Also, you have some wild [useless backticks](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks) there.

Comment: `<<'EOF'` to prevent expansions from happening in the parent shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when you try to `grep` the name of a process, you get an extra matching line for `grep` itself, for example:

```
$ ps xa | grep something
57386 s002  S+     0:00.01 grep something
```

So even when there is no matching process, you will get one matching line. You can fix that by adding a `grep -v grep` in the pipeline:

```
ps -e | grep stupid_test | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

As [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) suggested, an even better fix is writing the `grep` like this:

```
ps -e | grep [s]tupid_test
```

The meaning of the pattern is exactly the same, but this way it won't match `grep` itself anymore, because the string `"grep [s]tupid_test"` doesn't match the regular expression `/[s]tupid_test/`.

Btw I would rewrite your script like this, cleaner:

```
/bin/bash <<EOF
while :; do
  s=$(ps -e | grep [s]tupid_test)
  test "$s" || break
  echo test program is still running
  echo "$s"
  sleep 10
done
EOF
```

Or a more lazy but perhaps sufficient variant (hinted by [bryn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679904/bryn)):

```
/bin/bash <<EOF
while ps -e | grep [s]tupid_test
do
  echo test program is still running
  sleep 10
done
EOF
```

Comment: pgrep is a pretty useful tool for this sort of situation.

Comment: I observe that behavior of ps if i use `ps -x`, but not for `ps -e`

Comment: @aestrivex in which OS are you?

Comment: Never mind, the behavior seems to be erratic based on conditions I am not aware of -- for instance, counting the number of processes still seems to work properly, but the error goes away when I also grep -v grep

Comment: Ok in Linux `ps -e` works like you say for me too. In the middle, if instead of the line count, you let it print the matching processes with `ps -e | grep stupid_test`, then you should get some lines, with the matching processes that keep the loop from exiting

Comment: As a further optimization, `grep '[s]tupid_test` avoids matching itself in the first place.

Comment: Consider whether running the command a second time inside the loop (this time without -q) is really necessary or not. Running it once would also get rid of the race condition :)

Comment: @bryn true, I rewrote my answer